# ASP.NET Core API - How to insert extra fields into the DB after mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core Web API, I have this model:

Job:

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class JobCreationRequestDto
{
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
}

public class JobResponseDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

***One User can place several jobs***

Mapping:

```
public class JobMapProfile : Profile
{
    public JobMapProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<JobCreationRequestDto, Job>();
        CreateMap<Job, JobResponseDto>();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface IJobService
{
    Task<GenericResponseDto<JobResponseDto>> CreateJobAsync(JobCreationRequestDto requestDto);
}

    public async Task<GenericResponseDto<JobResponseDto>> CreateJobAsync(JobCreationRequestDto requestDto)
    {
        var response = new GenericResponseDto<JobResponseDto>();
        var userId = _userResolverService.GetUserId();
        var jobStatus = "Processed";

            try
            {
                var job = _mapper.Map<Job>(requestDto);
                _context.Jobs.Add(job);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                response.StatusCode = 201;
                response.Result = _mapper.Map<JobResponseDto>(job);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto()
                {
                    ErrorCode = 500,
                    Message = ex.Message
                };
            }
        } 
        return response;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost, Route("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<GenericResponseDto<JobResponseDto>>> CreateJob(JobCreationRequestDto request)
    {
        var response = await _service.CreateJobAsync(request);
        Response.StatusCode = response.StatusCode ?? StatusCodes.Status201Created;
        return new JsonResult(response);
    }
```

In the service, before await ***_context.SaveChangesAsync()*** is implemented, I want to include this:

> JobStatus = jobStatus;

> UserId = userId;

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set like  job.JobStatus = jobStatus;

Comment: After mapping the `requestDto` model to the `Job` model, you could set the `JobStatus` or `userid` for the `job` object, code like this: `var job = _mapper.Map<Job>(requestDto);  job.JobStatus = jobStatus;  _context.Jobs.Add(job);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mapping the `requestDto` model to the `Job` model, you could set the `JobStatus` or `userid` for the `job` object, code like this:

```
var job = _mapper.Map<Job>(requestDto);  
job.JobStatus = jobStatus;  
//job.UserId = userId;
_context.Jobs.Add(job);
```